# sql query to select a character by default when the column datatype is int

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

```
select B_id,amount,amount_paid,case when gr!=0 then gr else '-' end as goods_returned from tbl_addbill;
```

i even don't know if it is possible or not ,the datatype of column(gr) is int and i want to select (-) when gr !=0,However my query below is working fine,can anyone please tell me how to do this

```
select B_id,amount,amount_paid,case when gr!=0 then gr else 1 end as goods_returned from tbl_addbill;
```

Comment: You can convert `gr` to a string when `gr!=0`, for instance `case when gr!=0 then CONCAT(gr,'') else '-' end ...` (yes, I'm concatenating with an empty string; this converts `gr` to a string).

Comment: thanx @FDavidov,this answer solved my problem...

Comment: In that case, you may wish to up-vote it (if you hover your mouse at the left of my comment, you will see a small triangle).

Comment: i can't see any triangle,can u illustrate me...

Comment: I can't add a snapshot but it is very easy. Simple move your cursor to the left of (and a little beyond) my comment and you will see two signs appearing: a small triangle and a flag. Just click on the triangle and that's it. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: To make it easier for you, I added a formal answer to your question. You can mark it as the answer (again, below the up and down triangles at the left you will se a "V" that you can click on. Also, you can up-vote by clicking at the upper V to the left of the **answer** below (instead of the comment above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert `gr` to a string when `gr!=0`, for instance `case when gr!=0 then CONCAT(gr,'') else '-' end ...` (yes, I'm concatenating with an empty string; this converts gr to a string).